# Python: Merging two datasets using pd.merge

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes x and y of length 57734 and 22827 respectively. I want to merge x and y based on an unique column "unique_column" such that the resultant dataframe has 57734 rows, i.e., I want merge for each row of dataframe x. So far I have tried -

```
resultant_data = pd.merge(x, y, on='unique_column', how='inner')
```

```
resultant_data = pd.merge(x, y, on='unique_column', how='left')
```

```
resultant_data = x.merge(y, how='inner', on='unique_column')
```

```
resultant_data = x.merge(y, how='left', on='unique_column')
```

All of the 4 are giving me length 58408. Where are these extra rows coming from and how can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have duplicate indexes by any chance?

Comment: No, I do not have duplicate indices. And even if I did, why would that mess with the length of the dataframe?

Comment: Yes, use value_counts on 'unique_column' in both x and y dataframes, if you have a count greater than 1 an either or both dataframes, then you will create a cartesian product with this merge/join.

Comment: 'unique column' has 20193 unique values in dataframe x and 22797 unique values in dataframe y. What is the solution?. There are 26 blanks in either case

Comment: The extra rows come from having multiple indexes. You expect to have `57734` rows at the end, but the mapping from X to Y is not a 1 to 1 mapping. For instance, if you have a `df1` with 2 rows with the same idnex (e.g. [1, 1]) , and `df2` with 1 index (e.g. [1]), to which one of those rows should `df2`'s row map to? Now image if you have different unique values on both dataframes.

Comment: But which join is supposed to work the best in this situation?